# How can I Insert form data of a table into the database in php?

Tags: php, postgresql

PHP newbie here. I have a couple of questions so please don't discourage me since I'm just learning the PHP language.
So, my question is:
Currently, I am using an open source DB(POSTGRESQL) and I have just made my first PHP, a form-type page. How can I suppose to insert the form data of "table input type" into the database.

[See Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjlNg.jpg)

Please, I need the basics and not-so complicated solutions for this. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question). Also, be sure to take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: That image isn't helpful.

Comment: Sorry for my question description. 
What i meant is how can I save the data of a table input-type into PSQL

Answer (score 0):

learn some framework for example yii2 framework

just install

configure db connection

and create CRUD

[The Definitive Guide to Yii 2.0](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html)